# ParametricPlot not plotting domain end points

Tags: plotting

Consider the parametric plot

```
(*prettier Manipulate available at the end*)
ParametricPlot[{Cos@\[Theta], Sin@\[Theta]}^0.01, {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]/2}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 1.1}, {0, 1.1}}, AspectRatio -> 1, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Black]
```

which gives

[image: plot of the parametric curve]

The graph point $(0,1)$ at $\theta=\pi/2$ is not seen. Instead, the graph abruptly stops without reaching the y-axis.
**Hot to resolve this**?

---

Note that increasing `PlotPoints` doesn't work as the new points keep getting added between the leading and the ending points of the mesh. Also, the 'disconnection-from-y-axis' effect is apparent only for sufficiently low values of $n$ in the graph of $(\cos^n\theta,\sin^n\theta)$, in which case the curve gets progressively slower for $\theta>\pi/4$.

Prettier:

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{Cos@\[Theta], Sin@\[Theta]}^n, {\[Theta], 
   0, \[Pi]/2}, 
  Epilog -> {Dashed, {Thin, Gray, Circle[]}, Text[n, {0.1, 1.05}]}, 
  GridLines -> {{1}, {1}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1.1}, {0, 1.1}}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", Mesh -> All, 
  MeshStyle -> Black, 
  Method -> "BoundaryOffset" -> False], {{n, 0.01}, 0.001, 10, 0.01, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Comment: The problem is that your function is not very smooth. It makes a very fast change at Pi/2.  MMA has trouble with such specials functions

Comment: @DanielHuber The derivative's $\tan^{n-2}\theta$, so for small $n$ at $\pi/2$, it goes to zero, not blowup (as evident in the plot) - but I take your point (as for $\theta=\pi/2+\epsilon$, the abscissa is complex and graph abruptly ends)

Comment: @lineage: What you need it for? What is your final goal? If you want a parametric equation for a rectangle (or part of it) there are better equations.

Comment: @azerbajdzan Just curious - recreational...puzzled me that it figured out $\theta=0$ but not $\pi/2$

Answer (score 2):

Adding `WorkingPrecision -> 10` solves the problem. Also values for `n` in manipulate should be exact values.

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{Cos@Abs@(\[Theta] + \[Pi]/4), 
    Sin@Abs@(\[Theta] + \[Pi]/4)}^n, {\[Theta], -\[Pi]/4, \[Pi]/4}, 
  Epilog -> {Dashed, {Thin, Gray, Circle[]}, Text[n, {0.1, 1.05}]}, 
  GridLines -> {{1}, {1}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1.1}, {0, 1.1}}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", Mesh -> All, 
  MeshStyle -> Black, WorkingPrecision -> 10, 
  Method -> "BoundaryOffset" -> False, 
  Exclusions -> None], {{n, 1/100}, 1/1000, 10, 1/100, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

In case a parametric plot of rectangle is needed there are better choices for the [equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/69134/400836):

```
ParametricPlot[{2, 3}*{Abs@Sin@x Sin@x + Abs@Cos@x Cos@x, 
   Abs@Sin@x Sin@x - Abs@Cos@x Cos@x}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: +1. That's strange though;  *reducing* the precision makes the plot better? For me , `WorkingPrecision->17` and upwards is worse off.